# NPM: запуск глобального модуля из командной строки ubuntu linux

Tags: linux, node.js, npm

Устанавливаю глобально модуль:

```
sudo npm install -g learnyounode
```

Как мне запустить его из командной строки в linux? В windows можно было просто вводить название, если подключаешь его глобально.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете запустить его из командной строки. Вам надо вначале выполнить команду

```
  rehash
```

или открыть новое окно терминала.

Comment: Собственно на винде тоже надо перезапустить терминал, сами глобальные переменные окружения не подтянутся

Comment: использовал команду и перезапускал терминал

Comment: ошибка $ learnyounode
/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory

Comment: а если из командной строки запустить `node -v`, то какой результат?

Answer (score 0):

Обновление nodejs до последней версии решило проблему.